# Set max length to the digit display for a jQuery calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a jQuery ajax calculator and I have created a html for the interface.

My problem is that I want to set a max length for the display. That would be 8 digits only. After 8 digits it would display "Err" but I should be able to clear the "Err" after I click a number.

This is my code

Comment: `$display.text"Error";` is invalid. Try `$display.text("Error");`

Comment: I would also use `<input maxlength="8">` to keep the user from even *entering* more than 8 characters. I'd be rather annoyed if I kept getting error messages whenever I accidentally go over.

Comment: it is not working i think it is because i m not typing it the number. I use the click button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the modified code (with explanation):

```
$(function(){
    var $display = $('#display');
    $display.val(0);
    var key = null;

    $(document).on('click', 'button.number', function() { 
        if ($display.val().length >= 8) { //If there are 8 or more characters
            $display.val("Err"); //Write Err
        } else if ($display.val() == "Err") { //If it says Err
            $display.val("0"); //Set it to zero
        } else { //If everything's fine
            $display.val(($display.val() == "0" ? "" : $display.val()) + $(this).val()); 
            //Add the pressed number to the display 
            //The ternary statement means "if it's zero, replace, else append"
        }
    });
});
```